# How do I load object data from a save file?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, fstream, allocator

I'm working on a project that deals with creating two strings, a username and a password. The two elements make an object of an Account. In the main, there is an Array of Accounts that is initialized at 10. 
I have a Save & Quit option, which saves the Username on one line and the Password on the next in the same file. A pair of lines signifies another account.

My question is, how do you properly save the data from the Array of Accounts, then load the data from the previous Array of Accounts?

I get a `std::bad_alloc memory` error every time I try the `loadAccounts()` function. I've several different methods, but to no avail.

So far I've come up with this for saving the array (works just as it should so far) :

```
void saveAccounts(Account accs [], int numIndexes)
{
std::ofstream savefile("savedata.sav", std::ofstream::binary); // By re-initializing the file, the old contents are overwritten.
for (int i = 0; i < numIndexes; i++)
{
    savefile << accs[i].getUsername() << endl;
    savefile << accs[i].getPassword() << endl;
}
savefile.close();
}
```

As for my loading function I have :

```
Account* loadAccounts() // Load the data from the file to later print to make sure it works correctly.
{
cout << "LOADING ACCOUNTS!" << endl;
std::ifstream loadfile("savedata.sav", std::ifstream::binary);

Account * acc_arr; // The "Array" to be returned.
Account tmp_arr [10]; // The array to help the returned "Array."
acc_arr = tmp_arr; // Allowing the "Array" to be used and returned because of the actual array.
if (loadfile.is_open())
{
    int i = 0;
    while (loadfile.good())
    {
        cout << "Loadfile is good and creating Account " << i+1 << "." << endl; // For my own benefit to make sure the data being read is good and actually entering the loop.
        std::string user;
        std::getline(loadfile, user);
        std::string pass;
        std::getline(loadfile, pass);
        Account tmpAcc(user, pass);
        tmp_arr[i] = tmpAcc;
        ++i;
    }
    Account endAcc = Account(); // The default constructor sets Username to "NULL."
    tmp_arr[i] = endAcc;
}
loadfile.close();
cout << "ACCOUNTS LOADED SUCCESSFUL!" << endl;
return acc_arr;
}
```

I've gathered that I can return an array by using a pointer and an actual array to do that same, since an array can't actually be returned.

I try to use the returned array here, which I'm trying to "copy" over the loaded array to the Array that will actually be printed. Later, I'll print the array (acc_arr) to ensure that the loaded array was loaded successfully :

```
else if (selection == 'l' || selection == 'L')
{
Account * tmp_acc_arr = new Account [10];
    tmp_acc_arr = loadAccounts();
    _getch();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_t(10); i++)
    {
        if (tmp_acc_arr[i].getUsername() == "NULL")
        {
            break;
        }
        acc_arr[i] = tmp_acc_arr[i];
        cout << "Added Account " << i << " succesfully." << endl;
    }
}
```

The error is caused by this last block of code. I've checked to make sure the data copied correctly by using

EDIT: Awkward... by using an if statement to make sure the data within the `tmp_acc_arr` actually has data stored once it was returned and initialized in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp_arr` ist local in `loadAccounts` and on the stack. It will be invalid once `loadAccounts()` returns. Your return value is an invalid stack-pointer.

You could hand your pointer `tmp_acc_arr` to the function as an argument and fill it with the values from your file.
You should also check for overflow or better use STL containers like std::vector.

edit

---

```
void loadAccounts(Account * acc_memory, std::allocator<Account> alloc, size_t acc_array_size) // Load the data from the file to later print to make sure it works correctly.
{
  Account *end_of_construction = acc_memory;
  try
  {
    cout << "LOADING ACCOUNTS!" << endl;
    std::ifstream loadfile("savedata.sav", std::ifstream::binary);
    if (loadfile.is_open() && loadfile.good())
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for (size_t i=0; i<acc_array_size; ++i)
        {
          if (loadfile.good())
          {
            cout << "Loadfile is good and creating Account " << i+1 << "." << endl; // For my own benefit to make sure the data being read is good and actually entering the loop.
            std::string user, pass;
            std::getline(loadfile, user);
            if (loadfile.good())
            {
              std::getline(loadfile, pass);
              alloc.construct(end_of_construction++, user, pass);
            }
            else alloc.construct(end_of_construction++);
          }
          else alloc.construct(end_of_construction++);
        }
    }
    loadfile.close();
    cout << "ACCOUNTS LOADED SUCCESSFUL!" << endl;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    size_t num_constructed = end_of_construction-acc_memory;
    for (size_t i=0; i<num_constructed; ++i) alloc.destroy(acc_memory + i);
    throw;
  }
}
```

Used like

```
  size_t const num_elements = 10;
  std::allocator<Account> acc_alloc;
  Account * tmp_acc_arr = acc_alloc.allocate(num_elements);
  loadAccounts(tmp_acc_arr, acc_alloc, num_elements);
  // do stuff
  for (size_t i=0; i<num_elements; ++i) acc_alloc.destroy(tmp_acc_arr + i);
  acc_alloc.deallocate(tmp_acc_arr, num_elements);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a vector just to challenge myself. Now, I'm kicking myself. This was originally a Java-assignment from my fundamentals class, and I was trying to stick to using an array. I know vectors are far easier to use for situations like this.

Comment: @EricGross Instead of passing the pointer in and assigning temporary constructed elements via operator=(), you may also use either a combination of `malloc` and placement `new` or a combination of allocator<T>::allocate and allocator<T>::construct to control your memory and construction. I appended an example with allocators.

Comment: I tried running your solution, and it worked pretty well. I did run into the problem that there was an error reading an address in memory. The error pops up when I `destroy` and `deallocate` `tmp_acc_arr`.

Comment: EDIT: I'm assuming because there were too many objects created and the program is trying to access an empty address in memory to store in the actual Account Array.

Comment: Is the problem associated with destroy or deallocate?

Comment: Actually, I fixed that problem. The loop was going to far into the pointer where there were no more accounts, then later trying to read that address; I fixed that. Now, it will go through the whole load sequence like it should, but it's not copying the new pointer array elements to the actual `acc_arr` in main.

Comment: I found the problem, and the question is solved! I wasn't keeping track of the `accIndex` like I had been before. When the user would create a new Account, it would `++accIndex` that will later be passed in the printing method to know when to stop and not go to the end of the array, unless it was filled. Thank you so much @Pixelchemist

Comment: @EricGross The code does not construct the whole array unless enough lines are present in the file (which is in fact a bug in the code i posted) but i just fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You return a pointer that points to an array that is destroyed as soon as you exit the function. Using that pointer leads to undefined behavior, that is BAD.

As you observed, array is not a valid return type, so to return it actually you shall put it inside a struct, and return the struct.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of this? I'm fairly new to programming. I know a struct is pretty much a class, but I already have a class for Account, so I'm kinda confused about what you're referring to.

Comment: `struct AccountArr {Account arr[10];};`  and replace tmp_arr with this. Yuo can return this struct.   Certainly much better would be to use `std::vector<Account>` but I thought you aim a minimal change on existing code to learn a C way.

Comment: I appreciate the example. I'll implement later to see how it works. I tried passing it as an argument to the method and didn't do so properly. It's a work in progress. I know I can do it with vectors without a doubt, but like I said, this is more for the challenge.